# angular-meteor not working with Meteor 1.3 update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I have just updated the meteor application to Meteor 1.3 but now an error is raised as shown below :

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angular-meteor
```

Its breaking the functionalities of angular, below is the initialization code

```
angular.module('myApp',['angular-meteor','ui.router','ionic','ngCordova']);
```

I tried removing angular-meteor but its showing an error as angular is initialized twice.

Answer (score 1):

+1

Me too. Just taken me 30 mins to figure out it wasn't me by reverting to a previous version on my project. And workarounds at the moment?

Comment: Lucky I was on version control! Even the blog post regarding this update does'nt have any note about this.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem with: "meteor add angular-meteor-auth@1.0.0"
Then i do: "meteor update", to update my angular-meteor package. 
Now it works

Answer (score 0):

Please try the new angular-meteor `1.3.9_2` version and angular-meteor-auth `1.0.1`.
that should fix your issues